# If $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle QRS$ and $\triangle QRS \sim\triangle XYZ,$ does that imply $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle XYZ$?

Tags: geometry

If some triangle ABC is similar to triangle QRS, and QRS is similar to triangle XYZ, does that imply ABC is similar to XYZ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Have you thought about the problem? What have you tried? What do you know about similarity?

Comment: A first source of information could be [Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)) from Wikipedia: “Two triangles, both similar to a third triangle, are similar to each other (transitivity of similarity of triangles).”

Answer (score 1):

What's the definition of symmetric triangles.  That may depend on your test.  Some say if the corresponding angles are congruent the triangles are symmetric.

$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle QRS$ means $\angle A \cong \angle Q; \angle B \cong \angle R;\angle C \cong \angle S$.  And $\triangle QRS\sim \triangle XYZ$ means $\angle Q \cong \angle X; \angle R \cong \angle Y;\angle S \cong \angle Z$.

So $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle QRS$ and  $\triangle QRS\sim \triangle XYZ$ implies $\angle A \cong \angle Q \cong \angle X$. etc.  So the answer is a fairly obvious yes.

...

Alternatively the definition could be the side lengths are proportional be a constant.  If $QS = k\cdot AB$ and $XY = j\cdot QS$ then $XY = jk\cdot AB$ and ... the product of a constant is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Two triangles are similar if, but only if, they have the same set of three angle measures.